# Why doesn't object-fit affect width or height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a 240*240px image inside a 100*300px div (demo values, actual values vary and are unknown). I use `object-fit: contain` to make the image completely visible inside the div and also keep it's aspect ratio. The problem is that `object-fit` isn't modifying the width of the image, resulting in a weird "padding" (so to say).

[image]

How can I make the image take only as much width as required, instead of taking the original width?

Demo: http://codepen.io/alexandernst/pen/ONvqzN

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
img {
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex wrapper">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/240/240" />
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean "isn't modifying the width?" It has shrunk the image down to 100px height while keeping the width within aspect ratio. The padding is exactly 70px on each side because after it was resized to 100x100 there is 140px (70px * 2) left.

Comment: @theblindprophet I mean the total width that the `img` takes is more than the visible image. What I want to do is make the `img` element take as much width as the actual image (100px width in this case) instead of the original image's width (240px).

Comment: Ahh, so it would slide to the left and (for example) you could have room for other elements in the rest of the `div`?

Comment: @theblindprophet Yes, it would slide to the left and take only 100px, so there will be 200px available for other elements.

Comment: @theblindprophet No, the width/height is unknown. And there will be only 1 image. The rest of the available width will be used by, mainly, text.

Comment: Look at this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/redRoq

Comment: @theblindprophet Sorry, I forgot to add I'm looking for a no-js solution. But I'm keeping this if I can't find anything better.

Comment: This could be useful, does exactly what you want but wouldnt push other elements. JS needed. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNYJZa

Answer (score 1):

The `object-fit` property normally works together with `width`, `height`, `max-width` and `max-height`. Example:

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
img {
  object-fit: contain;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex wrapper">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/240/240" />
</div>
```

In fact, it works fine too even without `object-fit`, see this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sqmxx1wd/).

Answer (score -1):

```css
.wrapper {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/240/240);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

img {
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex wrapper">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/240/240" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is so much of a `No` I don't know where to start :/

Comment: Do you mean you don't understand the code I gave you, or is it not working??

Comment: It's not working, and you removed the fixed height, which shows the problem.