# Fitting image in custom grid in css html?

Tags: html, css

i made a custom grid and i want to add an image to one of the cells the image is appearing but it does not cover the full grid help??

this is the html snippet

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="one">back</div>
        <div class="two">
        <div class="two a">
            <!-- <img src="assets/mouth.png" alt="banner" > -->
            <img src="assets/astronaut.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="two b">
           <ul>
                <li id="prof-1">About</li>
                <li id="prof-2">Creations</li>
                <li id="prof-3">Contact</li>
                <li id="prof-4">Blog</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
            <div class="two c">c</div>
            <div class="two d">d</div>
        </div>
```

this is the css snippet

```
.two {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr ;
    gap: 4px 4px ;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    border-radius: 16px;
  }
  .a{
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden; 
  }
  .a img{
    width: 100%;
    object-fit:cover;
  }
```

[image: looking like this i want it to fill that cell]

Comment: use background: url(...) instead of img tag 

Comment: [The object-fit property normally works together with width, height, max-width and max-height.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636754/why-doesnt-object-fit-affect-width-or-height)